# terminal command - recursively traverse a folder, open all that is *.php in an application, like Dreamweaver

Tags: linux, terminal

title explains it all. 
I want to get all the php files in a given folder (and subfolders) then open all of them in dreamweaver.

I feel like I will need to use the find command and open and something to loop it. 
Sorry, still learning linux commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in Mac or Linux

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec PATH_TO_APP {} +
```